# Sharing "mapping" an audio device or mic to another PC.

Tags: networking, windows-8, audio, windows-8.1, microphone

I was wondering if it is possible to map an audio device or mic (3.5mm audio jack or USB) to another computer, sort of like you can with a drive or a printer?

My scenario: I have a security software running on a PC locked away upstairs at our shop. I can add external audio in and out devices to the cameras in this software as long as they're plugged into the PC. I want to avoid running 200ft of audio cable all over our place, and I have PC's located where I need sound recorded/sent. Is my question an option I could even entertain?

- security software: blue iris
- All PC's:          windows 8.1

Comment: I used to run a similar program called [iSpy](http://www.ispyconnect.com/). You can add microphone audio together with the video feed (handy if your cameras have mic built-in). Since it operates in a client-server configuration, the client simply pipes all data to the server.

Answer (score 7):

You can map any usb device over ethernet with the

http://www.eltima.com/products/usb-over-ethernet/

Regards.

Comment: From what I see, to use this is $90 per computer AND per device. If people actually buy this these guys are doing well =). This seems unpractical and probably has more complex uses, thanks though.

Comment: http://usbip.sourceforge.net/ is freeware but do not expact the same comfort :)

Comment: No, you pay for shared devices only, client-side app is for free.